# Conflict NewMessageReceived event

Tags: vb.net, websocket

I'm using a SuperWebSocket Server ([github](https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperWebSocket)); when some clients send messages at the same time, data lost.

my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim MyWebSocket As WebSocketServer = New WebSocketServer()
    MyWebSocket.Setup(prot)
    MyWebSocket.Start()

    AddHandler MyWebSocket.NewMessageReceived, AddressOf MyWebSocket_NewMessageReceived
End Sub
```

event:

```
Private Sub MyWebSocket_NewMessageReceived(session As WebSocketSession, value As String)
    Invoke(Sub()
               ListBox1.Items.Add(value)
           End Sub)
End Sub
```

After multiple clients send different messages at the same time, all events fire, but all messages are the same as the last client's message that arrived. It appears as if the last client's message creates a conflict and destroys the previous messages.

What's the solution?

Comment: From what I've understood, if two clients send a message at the same time, the last client's message gets shown while the previous client's message gets deleted?

Comment: @wEight That's right. `Client1.Send("Data1")` and `Client2.Send("Data2")` then ListBox1.Items are Data2, Data2.

Comment: Ahh, I see. My apologies. I've improved your question a bit and fixed some grammatical issues in case someone else doesn't get the question.